# Routing traffic through IPSec with NAT and IP Alias in pfSense

Tags: nat, ipsec, pfsense, tunnel

I have a pfSense firewall and I need to connect to a remote site (form my client). I'm running into several issues, and don't see traffic flowing in any way.

Here's my setup:

- `LAN` is `192.168.0.0/16`
- I have a `WAN` interface as the default gateway.
- I have a `WAN2` interface, that I'd like to use for the tunnel to the remote site.
- The remote site is asking my to connect using local IPs of `172.27.10.0/24`, as the won't be able to route my traffic otherwise. Their IP range (remote) is `10.100.0.0/16`.

This is what I did already

- Set up the IPSec tunnel. This works, and I can connect.
- I created a Virtual IP (Firewall -> Virtual IPs) of type `IP Alias`, in the `LAN` interface  with `IP Addresses` of `172.27.10.0/24`.
- I added routes in System -> Routing, so `10.100.0.0/16` goes through `WAN2`. Same for `172.27.10.0/24`, I added a route for that traffic to go through `WAN2`.
- On Firewall -> NAT, Outbount, I created a rule for WAN2, source `192.168.0.0/16`, Destination `10.100.0.0/16` and Translation Address the IP Alias I created (`172.27.10.0`).

With all this setup, I can't connect to any remote address. Even more, I don't see the tunnel connecting, so I guess it's not getting the traffic it needs.

I'm also not seeing any useful information in the firewall log.

Am I doing things right? (or slightly close to right?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't NAT like that, it hits IPsec before the NAT. You'll have to use 2.1 and its IPsec NAT capabilities in the phase 2. You can only map a /24 to a /24 so you won't be able to map your entire internal /16 to that /24, only a /24 out of the /16.

Comment: Thank you. I'll updated pfSense and post a comment if it works.