# Use a virtual Network in PFsense to redirect packages to device in another network

Tags: vpn, nat, ipsec, pfsense, ip-routing

I'm using PFsense and i have this situation:
[Network Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dd9f3.png)

I have a Pfsens already connected with "Site1" through OpenVPN. I can acess the "Device" normally in Pfsense network.

But now i have to make another VPN with "Concessionaria" but this network ask-me address in another range (172.25.16.0/24). Basically, the "Concessionaria" wants access "Device" through Pfsense using the address 172.25.16.5.

I try to create a IP Alias in Firewall -> Virtual IPs, and reference this network in Phase2 IPSEC with concessionaria and create a port forward to redirect 172.25.16.5 packages to 192.168.102.10, but doesn't work.

The problem is similar this link [Routing traffic through IPSec with NAT and IP Alias in pfSense](https://serverfault.com/questions/519339/routing-traffic-through-ipsec-with-nat-and-ip-alias-in-pfsense), but i don't find any solutions.

Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

So far, here's my progress:

Firewall -> Virtual IPs -> Add IP Alias:

Interface: LAN
Address: 172.25.16.1/24

Then i could make a IPSEC Túnnel using this address network in Phase2 with "Concessinaria". They can ping 172.25.16.1 normally.

So, i create a NAT 1:1 with these settings:

**Interface**:WAN

**External Subnet IP**: 172.25.16.5 (virtual address of "Device")

**Internal IP**: Any

**Destination**: 192.168.102.10

**NAT Reflection**: Enable

But the concessionária could not ping this IP. Missing some small detail ....